# How can I create a custom property in theos/logos?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, ivar, theos

Would it be possible to create a custom property in a hooked method using theos/logos?

example:

```
//define my custom property
@interface SBAwayController : NSObject {
    UIView *myCustomView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myCustomView;
@end

%hook SBAwayController
- (void)activate {
    //call original method
    %orig;

    //use my custom property
    if (tweakEnabled)
        [self.awayView addSubview:myCustomView];
}
%end
```

I've tried it as exampled above, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to create a singleton class that will hold your object/context. Take this example from this [Introspy hook class](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-iOS/blob/master/src/hooks/NSDataHooks.xm). `tracerStorage` is a variable defined outside the class and all hooks access it.

To apply it to your case, you can have an external variable NSMutableDictionary with the current `SBAwayController` as key and the property `myCustomView` as value.